# numpy save 2d array to text file

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I use

`np.savetxt('file.txt', array, delimiter=',')`

to save array to the file separated with comma. It looks like:

```
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 6
7, 8, 9
```

How can I save the array into the file shown as it is in the numpy format. In other words, it looks like:

```
[[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: why are you trying to save it like that? It'll just make it much more difficult to read back in when you want to use the data...

Comment: @MattDMo, I want to use the array somewhere else with only stdin feasible but not read from disk. I plan to use the naive copy+paste approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In [38]: x = np.arange(1,10).reshape(3,3)    

In [40]: print(np.array2string(x, separator=', '))
[[1, 2, 3],
 [4, 5, 6],
 [7, 8, 9]]
```

---

To save the NumPy array `x` to a file:

```
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf, linewidth=np.inf)  # turn off summarization, line-wrapping
with open(path, 'w') as f:
    f.write(np.array2string(x, separator=', '))
```

Comment: @DSM: Thank you; I simply didn't know it was there.

Comment: thanks for your reply. When I tried to use savetxt on tmp = np.array2string(x, separator=', '), it gives me "tuple index out of range" error. Can you please show me how to save your result into text file? Thanks

Comment: @ChuNan: I've added some code to show how to save `x` to a file. That should work for moderate-sized arrays. One drawback however is that if `x` is huge, `np.array2string` would generate one gigantic string. That's not memory-friendly. In that case, it would be better to iterate through the rows of `x` and print them chunks at a time.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the first format for copy-pasting as well:

```
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> bio = BytesIO('''\
... 1, 2, 3
... 4, 5, 6
... 7, 8, 9
... ''') # copy pasted from above
>>> xs = np.loadtxt(bio, delimiter=', ')
>>> xs
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys

file = "<you_file_dir>file.txt"

sys.stdout = open(file, 'w')

d = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
l__d1 = d[0:3]
l__d2 = d[3:6]
l__d3 = d[6:9]

print str(l__d1) + '\n' + str(l__d2) + '\n' + str(l__d3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
def writeLine(txt_file_path, txtArray: list):
   l = len(txtArray)
   counter = 0
   with open(txt_file_path, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
       for item in txtArray:
           counter += 1
           row = [str(x) for x in item]
           fstr = '\t'.join(row)+'\n' if counter<l else '\t'.join(row)
           f.writelines(fstr)

x = np.arange(16).reshape(4,4)
writeLine('a.txt',x)
```